# uninstall problem in wine program

Tags: wine, uninstall, adobe

I have installed adobe illustrator 8 in my wine. Though it didn't install properly and now I'n can't remove/use it by using wine uninstaller as well. When I start uninstalling the adobe illustrator it's start uninstalling but after few seconds my PC doesn't respond. It's hang.I'm using Ubuntu 12.04LTS,wine 1.4.1 from Ubuntu software center and wine tricks. Also I have installed adobe illustrator from CD.Moreover, I have also installed adobe Photoshop and it's working well. So, please tell me the solution. How can I remove adobe illustrator from wine?

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the `.wine` directory in your home directory. You may have to press `crtl-h` to unhide hidden files. If your a mouse person find this option in the view menu, or other menus depending on which file manager you use. If you used winetricks, or PlayonLinux then the directory will have a different name. Winetricks will likely name the directory in a similar fashion to the program name, and PlayonLinux bottles are in `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix`. I would refer to the wine app db for further reading on how to install this, I'm sure it's possible, you may be missing some dependencies.

After Removing the directory, issue a winecfg (if you used vanilla wine) from the console to rebuild the `.wine` directory, if you would like to try again!

Comment: but it doesn't work

Comment: what doesn't work? Give me more information.

Comment: your mentioned process I already tried and failed before you write. So, please find something new! Thanks

Comment: are you talking about the menu entries, because all you have to do to remove those is delete the .desktop files, some wine programs when un-installed will leave behind these entries, and clutter up your menu, i think they are in `/usr/share/applications`, but i could be wrong, search for them, or try to right click on the entries themselves or edit your menu and hide them. Since you removed the `.wine` directory the application is gone, and the un-installer hanging tells me that something is wrong with it, if this fails try to run the un-installer from a console, and give it's output